# Joined Blog, User, UserActive model but api showing only blog and user table data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new on django-rest-api. trying to learn myself. Please help me.

I am having problem getting Blog, User, and UserActive model data altogether

getting only Blog and User model data like this:

```
[
    {
        "blog_id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$260000$sGvXY1BbGTEeCADbzdLe9m$Pad1fd3N7CYVvz1jQv5xMRTxikqyOFnfWr6bmqUfv5o=",
            "last_login": "2021-04-11T13:46:49.739205Z",
            "is_superuser": true,
            "username": "superuser",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "email": "superuser@email.com",
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "date_joined": "2021-04-08T13:26:43.174410Z",
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": []
        },
        "title": "first blog",
        "description": "hola",
        "image": "/images/phone.jpg",
        "create_at": "2021-04-08T14:24:51.122272Z",
        "update_at": "2021-04-08T14:37:00.287746Z"
    }
]
```

but I want to get data from exteded User Model 'LastActive' for that i also added ser.objects.all().select_related('useractive') on views.py

serializer.py is :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'



class UserActiveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserActive
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py is:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_users(request):
    user = User.objects.all().select_related('useractive')
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_blogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer = BlogSerializers(blogs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py is:

```
class UserActive(models.Model):
    user_active_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False, null=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)


class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=False,blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    update_at =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)


    def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.user.username}     {self.title}       {self.create_at}    {self.update_at}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand your question right, is this what you are trying to get??

```
class BlogSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserActiveSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Try removing or changing the value `depth` to 2, according to your need.

Comment: does not work. I get these errors``` "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `UserActiveSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'."```